# what is the alternative of jboss Coyote Subsystem in Web Sphere Application Server

Tags: websphere

In JBoss EAP we have coyote subsytem which is responsible for all incoming and Outgoing HttpRequest. 
Is there any similar subsytem or api in WebSphere Applictaion server.

I am looking for single point entry and exit for HTTP Request?Htt Response in webSphere Application server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent component in WebSphere is the "Channel Framework". It's a stack of channels such as TCP, SSL, and HTTP that the "web container" / servlet engine sits on top of.

It's sometimes abbreviated CHF, or referred to as individual channels such as the "TCP Channel".

Comment: thanks Covener. do you have any infor on which jar/class is reponsible for it.